# match the whole string recursively with a regex in c++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am doing the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

typedef std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> RegexIterator;
typedef std::string String;
typedef std::regex Regex;


bool isComplyingToRegex(String& s,Regex &re){
    String total="";
    RegexIterator it(s.begin(), s.end(), re);
    RegexIterator it_end;
    while(it!=it_end){total+=it->str();++it;}
    if(s!=total){return false;}
    else return true;
}


int main(){
    String name="/jk/";
    String pat = R"(\s*/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/\s*([gi]{0,2})\s*(;\s*|$))";
    Regex multi_re (pat);
    std::cout<< isComplyingToRegex(name,multi_re);
}
```

The string `/jk/` is not supposed to match but it somehow does. The least condition to match is, there should be exactly 3 slashes (`/`), but `/jk/` with two slashes match. For more complex string, it works correctly. I am only seeing this behavior with this simple string.

If I use `std::regex_search` with that string, it returns true too.

Is something wrong with my code or regex syntax?

[regex101link](https://regex101.com/r/gI4cT9/1)

Comment: Some `std::regex` implementations are known to be broken, try another one, or use `boost::regex`.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I am using gcc 4.9.2

Comment: Yep. Too old. [See here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91371503c7299fd6)

Comment: @ILI Nope, he's using a raw string.

Comment: least condition to match is, there should be exactly 3 slashes, so how come /jk/mk/ match? Is it that total count of / in your string should be 3 no matter where they appear?

Comment: How about using : `String pat = R".*\/\w+\/\w+\/.*";`

Comment: @svasa that won't serve my purpose. I am taking a regex of the format : `/search/replace/modifier;` from the user, where the modifier is optional, and the `;` can be ommited if it's the end of the string. Also, slash is not allowed in `search` or `replace` part and the `modifier` can be either `g` or `i` or neither.

Comment: Let's be clear though that `/search/replace/modifier;` has nothing to do with regular expressions, it's your target string.

Comment: @sln yap........ that's right... That's the input and I am parsing it with the above regex to see if the user has passed a valid regex format (according to my conventions)

Comment: I'd recommend to use this http://www.regexformat.com app to test C++ regexes, it uses a variation of boost::regex engine.

Comment: A fyi, you cannot parse regex delimiters this way. It's more involved than that.

Comment: @sln you lost me, can you explain a bit...

Comment: @sln may be you are talking about the fact that, I can't get all the things I want from it this way. Well, I just need to do the check here that's all. I have another function which uses token iterator to parse it and get the parts separated.

Comment: On a basic level, the regex delimiter must be separated from the regex itself. It's sort of like (but not quite) parsing a string, before using it. This means the delimiter has to be un-escaped (if escaped). This is generally ok with `/` but it could be a problem if using a metacharacter as a delimiter. Example using the delimiter `+`. The regex is `9\+9`. Then with the delimiter added it's `+9\+9+`. When the regex engine parses the delimiter out, it becomes `9+9`, which now the `+` is a metachar instead of a literal. No big deal, but that's how it works.

Comment: In that example, even if you were to add an extra escape so it becomes `+9\\+9+` it parses out to `9\\+9`. So, there is the rub.

Comment: @sln , yes, of course, I am aware of that, thanks for the reminder though. `/` is used explicitly and it is the only delimiter that is allowed and the regex itself (between the delimters) can not contain any slash.

Comment: If you don't allow a slash between the delimiters `/ ... /` then you cripple the regex to not match slash. You must parse escaped delimiters literals. To do that you need a regex like this `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*/` to find a delimiter. You would use that in place of your `/` in your regex.

Comment: @sln escaped delimiters aren't allowed either....:D I am working with filenames and want to prevent any use of `/` at all. I am going to note your example though, I didn't have that piece of info.

Comment: Ok, I see. Sounds good !